# Does an antiDeSitter space compensate the vacuum energy?

Tags: vacuum, cosmological-constant, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Sometimes I read here or there that a problem with the electroweak vacuum is that it implies a huge positive cosmological constant. On other side, I also read that AdS spaces are not useful anymore for real world observations because we need to get a small positive cosmological constant at the end of the day.

I wonder, is it not possible to compensate one problem against the other? This is, having in the Lagrangian an anti-deSitter space with negative radius or order 246 GeV, and then breaking of the electroweak vacuum so that the final result is slightly positive.

Comment: There are various relationships between dS and AdS, and so on, but your chain of thoughts is completely irrational. What does the cosmological constant have to do with the Higgs vev? They have even different units but even if you exponentiate to match the units, they're still completely different. The Higgs potential is just one among many contributions to the cosmological constant and a source of an analogous but milder problem than the C.C. problem. And so on. May I summarize your question as asking whether you have invented a wonderful new theory of the C.C.? In that case, the answer is No.

Comment: So, the answer is that it is possible to add both contributions, from AdS and from electroweak vacuum, and that this is not a new finding but standard lore?

Answer (score 2):

In KKLT, a stable AdS vacuum is uplifted to a metastable dS vacuum by the addition of antibranes. And one way to get a Higgs mechanism in string theory is to have a single stack of branes separated into two, parallel, very close stacks.

So let's suppose we have a KKLT-like construction in which there are two such adjacent stacks of antibranes. Since the existence of a Higgs VEV makes a modest contribution to the c.c. in field theory, it seems likely that in the string scenario, there will also be a modest contribution to the vacuum energy coming specifically from the existence of the gap between the two antibrane stacks, and not just from the existence of the antibranes per se - though I couldn't tell you the details, I'm just reasoning by analogy with field theory.

However... again reasoning from the field-theoretic precedent... the contribution to the vacuum energy from the stringy Higgs VEV ought to be very small compared to other contributions whose weigh-off is the usual basis of the KKLT construction. So it may be unlikely for the stringy Higgs VEV, specifically, to be a "special" part of the total c.c.

That is, we are saying that the observed c.c. is "X", the contribution from the stringy Higgs VEV is "H", and so the sum of all the other contributions to the c.c. must have been "X-H". And it seems this final quantity must be tuned very precisely, for the "H" contribution to be what pushes it over the line, because "H" is going to be much smaller than a lot of what has gone into "X-H".

It's logically possible that there could be some reason, e.g. [some mysterious symmetry](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3556), whereby the tiny "H" contribution is what specifically tips the balance into positive vacuum energy. But that would require new ideas and new evidence.

Comment: I think I can say this much about the "details" of "H", that it comes from closed-string gravitons coupling to open strings that connect the two parallel antibrane stacks of the scenario. (These "open strings of the gap" would produce SM yukawa couplings by interacting with e.g. other *open* strings existing at nearby brane-stack intersections; see braneworld models of Ibanez, Marchesano et al.)